# R convert nested values to new columns and rows

Tags: r

With a dataframe like the following:

```
currencyDetails = c("Dollar:40, Euro:80, valid",
               "Yen:400, Pound:50",
               "Dollar:40, Pound:50, currency",
               NA)
```

Can someone recommend a method to append to that dataframe new columns and rows that correspond to the pairs and values in the each row please?  The number of pairs or values in each string is not fixed, and not ordered.

For sample output:

```
Dollar = c(40,NA,NA,NA)
Pound = c(NA,50,50,NA)
Euro = c(80,NA,NA,NA)
Yen = c(NA,400,NA,NA)
valid = c(1,0,0,0)
currency = c(0,0,1,0)
df = data.frame(Dollar, Pound, Euro,Yen,valid, currency)
cbind(currencyDetails, df)

                currencyDetails Dollar Pound Euro Yen valid currency
1     Dollar:40, Euro:80, valid     40    NA   80  NA     1        0
2             Yen:400, Pound:50     NA    50   NA 400     0        0
3 Dollar:40, Pound:50, currency     NA    50   NA  NA     0        1
4                          <NA>     NA    NA   NA  NA     0        0
```

I think it's different to the supplied previous answers as there's the extra complexity of splitting out the key:value pair, it's not that each element is turned into a column name as is.  For example, Pound:50 is not the column, Pound is, with 50 as it's value.

Comment: Please show your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
splitted<-trimws(unlist(strsplit(aDataFrame,",")))

t(bind_rows(sapply(splitted[grep(":",splitted)],strsplit,split=":")))
          [,1]     [,2] 
Dollar:40 "Dollar" "40" 
Euro:80   "Euro"   "80" 
Yen:400   "Yen"    "400"
Pound:50  "Pound"  "50"
```

Update

```
df<-data.frame(t(bind_rows(sapply(splitted[grep(":",splitted)],strsplit,split=":"))))
> library(reshape2)
> acast(df, X2 ~ X1)
Using X2 as value column: use value.var to override.
    Dollar Euro Pound Yen 
40  40     <NA> <NA>  <NA>
400 <NA>   <NA> <NA>  400 
50  <NA>   <NA> 50    <NA>
80  <NA>   80   <NA>  <NA>
Levels: 40 400 50 80
```

Comment: Thank you Terru, providing a potential solution is faster than my ability to provide sample output.  Can you suggest a change that would convert the first column in your version to column headers like the output i put in above since?

Comment: Updated answer moving in this direction, but you have to adapt this solution

Comment: Thanks Terru, I'll follow your advice and see what I cam come up with.